# Enforce derived implementations to do something, what is the best practice?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I'm not even sure there is an answer\ sutiable design to this question but its worth to ask...
I have an abstract class (servlet) that get data from some clients with (among others) processResults method (abstract), and onResultsReceived (not abstract)

```
public abstract class dataServlet implements HttpServlets {
      protected onDataReceived(){//blah blah}
      public abstract void processData();
}
```

I onDataReceived method i'm doing some common things that is neccessary for all the implementations of processData method. If tomorrow someone will add new implementation of dataServlet, i want to be sure he will invoke onDataReceived in his processData implementation.
Is there any way, known design to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you should consider the [*template method pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_pattern), as it enforces a specific order of execution, without requiring the author of the derived class to call stuff.

The pattern is:

```
abstract class Base {
    public doActivity() {
        doCommonStuff();
        doSpecificStuff();
        doOtherCommonStuff();
        doOtherSpecificStuff();
    }

    protected abstract void doSpecificStuff();
    protected abstract void doOtherSpecificStuff();

    private final void doCommonStuff() { ... }
    private final void doOtherCommonStuff() { ... }
}
```